# Jquery/Ajax FormData file upload specific fields instead of entire form

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my form

```
<form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    
    <input class="image-input" type="file" name="image_self">
    <input class="image-input" type="file" name="image_cover">
    <input class="image-input" type="file" name="image_file">
    <a id="uploadImage" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Image</a>

</form>
```

and this is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#uploadImage').click(function() {

            var token =  $('input[name="csrftoken"]').attr('value');

            var formUpload = $('#myform').get(0);

            var formData = new FormData(formUpload);
        
            $.ajax({
            url: '/image-upload/',
            data : formData,
            method : 'POST',
            headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': token 
                    },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('error');
            },
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
        });


        })
    })
</script>
```

Currently, my form is working very well but i don't want like that way.

I want to upload or send data in FormData only `image_file` fields instead of entire form fields

Can anyone help to send specific fields in formData?

I tried like this but it has no response:

```
var formData = new FormData($('input[name=image_file]'));
```

Can anyone please hlep me to get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target specific fields you can `append()` them to the `FormData` object, instead of giving the entire form to the constructor. Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image_self', $('input[name="image_self"]')[0].files[0]);
```